# How to set different text for a QDockWidget's tab and window title?

Tags: python, pyqt4, titlebar, qdockwidget

I've subclassed `QDockWidget` and I am setting the title-bar text via `myDockWidget.setWindowTitle("Some text")`. However, I'd like to display different text in the tab when the widget is docked. In other words, when the widget is docked, I'd like to display one string in the title-bar and a different string in the tab:

[image]

Is this possible and, if so, how can it be done?

Comment: You could indicate with an image what you want to obtain.

Comment: Added image to illustrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by reimplementing the `paintEvent` and overriding the default title-bar text. The window-title must still be used to set the tab-text:

```
class DockWidget(QtGui.QDockWidget):
    _title_text = None

    def titleText(self):
        if self._title_text is None:
            return self.windowTitle()
        return self._title_text

    def setTitleText(self, text):
        self._title_text = text
        self.repaint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        if self.isFloating():
            options = QtGui.QStyleOptionFrame()
            options.initFrom(self)
            painter.drawPrimitive(QtGui.QStyle.PE_FrameDockWidget, options)
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionDockWidgetV2()
        self.initStyleOption(options)
        options.title = self.titleText()
        painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_DockWidgetTitle, options)

dockWidget = DockWidget()
dockWidget.setWindowTitle('Tab Text')
dockWidget.setTitleText('Title Text')
```

PS:

Note that another option is to use [setTitleBarWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget). However, the huge disadvantage of this, is that you lose all the native window decorations.

Comment: For PyQt5, replacing `QtGui` to `QtWidgets`, and `QStyleOptionDockWidgetV2` to `QStyleOptionDockWidget` works for me.